# sbt output in jenkins giving junk characters

Tags: jenkins, sbt, sbt-assembly, jenkins-docker

Prints the following in output

```
> [A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.13 ...[0m
[A
```

instead of

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.13 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.13 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.13 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.13 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.13 ...
```

how can i get rid of the excess junk characters? I am using jenkins to build the scala project using sbt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Turn off the color output](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options) (from [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/issues/6)):

```
-Dsbt.log.noformat=true
```

Comment: While starting SBT us e below command   `$ SBT -Dsbt.log.noformat=true`

Comment: link to the latest version sbt command line options https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options